# webparts and firefox in vs2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if they was anyway to get webparts working in other browsers except IE if not is they any other free alternative that has the same drag and snap and saving capabilities?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

seems there are a few changes to enable support for Firefox

see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/03/24/Drag-and-Drop-ASP.NET-2.0-Web-Parts-in-FireFox-_2800_with-Atlas_2900_.aspx) article

Comment: none of the links work in this article and i will be using asp.net 4.0 not 2.0

Comment: damn it appears the link that it links to is broken, still some of the comments there might help

Answer (score 0):

have a look here, it should work in all browsers:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/147797/Webpart-Portlet-development-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Framewo

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DropThings](http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/) framework, it works in all browsers.